# for scorecardpy.woe_bin package in python I am getting "TypeError: unhashable type: 'numpy.ndarray'"

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy-ndarray

Python is having `scorecardpy` library for scorecard development which is alternative to R pacakge  `scorecardpy`

but while running woe_binning from scorecardpy as follow

```py
  bins = sc.woebin(df_temp,y=target_var,positive='bad|1') 

  
  #df_temp is dataframe with all columns having 'float64' data type
  #y is binary variable having data type 'int'
```

I was getting error for few variables

```py
TypeError: unhashable type: 'numpy.ndarray
```

others were getting binned properly.
i tried finding. difference between variable where binning was successful vs binning was failing basis few parameters as follows

- Null value
- dtypes
- shape

in order to understand the pattern with following code

```py
unhashable_nparray = []
successfully_binned = []


for j,i in enumerate(df3.columns):

    try:
        print(i)
        df_temp = pd.DataFrame()
        df_temp[i] = df3[i]
        df_temp[target_var] = y
        bins = sc.woebin(df_temp,y=target_var,positive='bad|1') 
        successfully_binned.append(i)
        print(i,"---{a}---{b}----{c}--{d}---{z}----Success".format(z =df3[i].nunique()  ,a = df3[i].shape, b=df3[i].isna().sum(),c=type(df3[i]),d=df3[i].dtypes))

    except TypeError:
        unhashable_nparray.append(i)
        print(i,"---{a}---{b}----{c}--{d}---{z}----Fail".format(z =df3[i].nunique(),a = df3[i].shape, b=df3[i].isna().sum(),c=type(df3[i]),d=df3[i].dtypes))
```

> but I could not find any pattern.

what could be the cause of this?

Answer (score 0):

**Here is the solution**

This error is already reported.
and getting discussed [here](https://github.com/ShichenXie/scorecardpy/issues/94) but unfortunately the language is Chinese it is difficult to read.

this error doesn't necessarily mean that your dataframe is uncleaned.or having not expected datatype

please check  your pandas version

```py
import pandas as pd
pd.__version__
```

if output is `> 1.4.0` that means you are using recent version of pandas than what scorecardpy is expecting

as of today  scorecardpy expects you to work on `pandas version <= 1.3.5`

so please install `pandas == 1.3.5`